# About the use of "threatened" in "before President Trump's threatened tariffs on Mexico are supposed to kick in."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is the use of *threatened* in:

> before President Trump's **threatened** tariffs on Mexico are supposed to kick in.

correct? The only definition I know of *threatened* is *endangered*.

Source: [This](https://m.youtube.com/watch?t=0m2s&v=AcQAZyLRRU4&t=0m1s) video clip.

Comment: What kind of tariffs are they? They're not *actual* tariffs currently in force - they're "hypothetical, future" tariffs that Trump has ***threatened*** to impose (unless Mexico does certain things he's asked for).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "on Mexico" plays a key role in the overall meaning of the sentence, had it not been there the meaning of the sentence would be completely changed in the sense that " threatened tarrifs" would mean "endangered tarrifs", whereas "threatened tarrifs on Mexico" means something totally different, isn'it?

Comment: That would be a perverse reading, to say the least! But the fact that these "threatened" tariffs might be further qualified by ***...on Mexico*** doesn't in and of itself have any bearing on whether they're being characterised as ***endangered*** or *[intimidatingly] **pending***. To the extent that tariffs *could* be "endangered", it makes no difference who the tariffs are targeting, and/or whether that target is explicitly specified or not.

Answer (score 1):

[The ODE](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/threaten) gives the meaning of ***threaten*** as ***state one’s intention to take hostile action against someone in retribution for something done or not done***. In this case, President Trump has indicated that tariffs will be imposed on Mexico if the Mexican government does not take appropriate and effective steps to reduce migrant transit of Mexico to the US border, where they attempt to enter the United States illegally - that is, he has ***threatened*** Mexico with tariffs on their US trade if they do not comply with US demands.

Comment: Is the "s" in "Trump's" the possesive "s" or is it  a compact form of "Trump has"?

Comment: This is the possessive; the threats belong to (were made by) the President.